# How can i write a regular expression for to match string staring with alphabets and ending with digits

Tags: regex, qtp, hp-uft

i want to match the strings which is listed below other than than that whatever the string is it should not match

```
rahul2803
albert1212
ra456
r1
```

only the above mentioned strings should match in the following group of data

```
rahul
2546rahul
456
rahul2803
albert1212
ra456
r1
rahulrenjan
r4ghyk
```

i tried with `([a-z]*[0-9])` but it's not working.

Comment: Define "not working". What happens, what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: i wanna match a string starting with alphabets and ending with numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions `*` means *zero or more* so your regex matches zero letters. If you want *one or more* use `+` (`\d` means digit).

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are fun to solve once you get the hang of the syntax.

This one should be pretty straight:

1. Start with a letter. `^[a-z]` (I am not taking the case of capital
   letters here, if they are then `^[a-zA-Z]` )
2. Have multiple letters/digits in between `.*`
3. End the string with a digit `[0-9]$`

Combine all 3 and you get:

```
^[a-z].*[0-9]$
```